# Error when using paranoic gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am new to rails.. Kindly please forgive if this question do not meet your standard..I am using paranoic gem for soft deletion..  I have added the following lines to my model

`acts_as_paranoid sentinel_value: DateTime.new(0)`

My controller code is

```
def trash_admin
  @order_summary = OrderSummary.only_deleted
end

def delete_trash
  @order_summary = OrderSummary.find params[:id]
  @order_summary.really_destroy!
  flash[:notice] = "Order Deleted Permanently!!!"
  redirect_to :action=>"trash_admin"
end
```

And I am getting the following error..

Couldn't find OrderSummary with 'id'=1 [WHERE "order_summaries"."deleted_at" = ?]

I think value for deleted_at column is not passing.. Dont know how to overcome this..

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delete_trash method doesn't find the item because the item is deleted.

The `trash_admin` method uses the `.with_deleted` scope that enables the finder to look in deleted items. You also need to add it to the `delete_trash` method's find statement, otherwise it will not find items that are in deleted state.

Like this:

```
@order_summary = OrderSummary.only_deleted.find params[:id]
```